# C++ Command-Line program design UI?

Tags: c++, user-interface

I am given a task to develop an C++ command-line(terminal, I am using, will run the program in Linux/Ubuntu) display. But I dont like the command-line design, is there anyway to improve the UI design?

Note: I must run the program in terminal!!

Comment: So you were given a task to do something with the command line, but you'd rather work with the GUI? This sounds like a conversation you should have with your boss.

Comment: The truth is it very difficult to beat the system, it takes big efforts and results usually suck anyway. So you either accept the usual ways of doing work or switch to a system you are satisfied with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`ncurses`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).  It's a lib to be able to put text wherever you want in the terminal, so you can effectively draw, ascii-art style in the terminal.  It's also a very old library, so it may be a little tedious to use.

Answer (score 1):

I developed a [simple multiplatform console management library](http://webs.uvigo.es/jbgarcia/asignaturas/FP/) some time ago.

You can use it at least on Linux and Windows. It uses native calls in Windows, and standard escape codes in other platforms.

If you just want to show some colors, position the cursor, and so on, you can use it in a matter of minutes without struggling with ncurses.

The documentation (generated with doxygen) is included in the Zip file.